# Create IMAP account in Outlook 2007 programmatically

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-object-model

we're rolling out a new voicemail system, and trying to figure out a way to programmatically add a new IMAP account to a user's Outlook.

Idea is that I create a form that takes a bunch of fields needed, and creates it all for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would take a look at [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/) In the commercial version there is a bonus dll "profman" Which allows you play with the outlook profiles.

Comment: And for POP3 accounts, Redemption exposes RDOSession.Accounts.AddPOP3Account: http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOAccounts.htm